# Solução direta (e bonita) para arrumar base usando dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho a seguinte base de inadimplentes:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lead_15 = c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
  lead_30 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
  lead_60 = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),

  inib_15 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  inib_30 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
  inib_60 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),

  motivo_15 = c("A","","","","","","","","D","","","","","",""),
  motivo_30 = c("","","","B","","","A","","","","","","","B",""),
  motivo_60 = c("","","","","C","","","","","","B","D","","","")
)
```

Eu quero uma solução onde exista uma linha para cada lead (3 linhas) onde a primeira coluna seja a soma do respectivo lead, soma do respectivo inib e uma coluna para cada motivo (A, B, C, D) onde tenha a quantidade desses motivos.

```
LEAD    | QTD | INIB | A | B | C | D |
--------|-----|------|---|---|---|---|
lead_15 |  4  |  2   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
--------|-----|------|---|---|---|---|
lead_30 |  5  |  3   | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
--------|-----|------|---|---|---|---|
lead_60 |  4  |  3   | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

É um problema relativamente simples que consigo resolver mas com muitos pedaços de código e contas separadas. Quis perguntar aqui pois sei que pode existir uma solução direta usando o `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui pensar numa forma de fazer em apenas uma expressão. Mas não acho que a seguinte organização seja ruim.

```
motivo <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("motivo")) %>%
  gather(key, motivo) %>%
  separate(key, c('x', 'grupo')) %>%
  filter(motivo != "") %>%
  group_by(grupo, motivo) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread(motivo, n, fill = 0)

inib <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("inib")) %>%
  gather(key, inib) %>%
  filter(inib != 0) %>%
  separate(key, c('x', 'grupo')) %>%
  group_by(grupo) %>%
  summarise(inib = sum(inib))

qtd <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("lead")) %>%
  gather(key, lead) %>%
  separate(key, c('x', 'grupo')) %>%
  group_by(grupo) %>%
  summarise(inib = sum(lead))

final <- left_join(qtd, inib) %>% left_join(motivo)
```

Claro que, se você souber que os motivos sempre serão "A", "B", "C" e "D",
a solução do @Fernando é melhor. Essa solução assume que o número de motivos pode ser variável dependendo da base, assim como o número de tipos de "lead".

Comment: Excelente resposta. Eu também sempre tento resolver as de forma 'genérica', para não ter que ficar escrevendo as variáveis na mão, e se houver mudança na base o código continua o mesmo.

Só uma questão a mais: como cada linha possui somente 1 lead (é 15, 30 ou 60), a variável 'motivo' poderia ser somente uma coluna (sem estar explícito se é 15, 30 ou 60).
Nesse resposta ficaria muito mais complexa? Como seria o 'split' da coluna motivo em 3 colunas?

Comment: @TheBiro acho que nada muda na resposta! Desde que a coluna tenha o nome começado com "motivo".

Answer (score 3):

Não sei o que exatamente você quis dizer com solução direta, porém segue uma solução usando dplyr e tidyr em uma (longa) linha.

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("motivo")), 
                 funs(A = if_else(. == "A", 1, 0), 
                      B = if_else(. == "B", 1, 0), 
                      C = if_else(. == "C", 1, 0), 
                      D = if_else(. == "D", 1, 0))) %>%
  select(-matches("motivo_\\d{2}$")) %>%
  gather %>% mutate(key = gsub("(.+)(_)(\\d{2})_(.$)", "\\1\\4_\\3", key)) %>%
  separate(key, c("tipo", "grupo")) %>%
  group_by(tipo, grupo) %>% summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% spread(tipo, value)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
grupo  inib  lead motivoA motivoB motivoC motivoD
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    15     2     4       1       0       0       1
2    30     3     5       1       2       0       0
3    60     3     4       0       1       1       1
```

Comment: Não especifiquei direito, mas oq quis dizer era uma solução com as funções do dplyr, de modo que ele já montasse a base para todos os leads, e não um de cada vez, cheio de contas, 'ifs' e etc, que era como eu estava fazendo... Ainda mais pq tem muitas outras variáveis além dessas. E eu não conhecia o 'tidyr', contém muitas funções que eram quais eu estava procurando.